# Boolean in Retrofit from a json object

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit

I have a status in my json object that was set to boolean. My main problem is that in every handled time let's say 5 secs it will add another set of status which is the previous status displayed and it has no end. I'm not sure what triggered this can anyone help me with this I'm just starting to learn android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update 2

You need to clear the old content of the TextView before appending any new content

```
//hardware
hardwareStatus.setText("") // Clear old response data from TextView
for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getHardware().length; i++){
  // Your logic
}

//software
softwareStatus.setText("") // Clear old response data from TextView
for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getSoftware().length; i++){
  // Your logic
}
```

### Update 1

You're seeing the old results because your appending to the results TextView

```
hardwareStatus.append(spannable);                  
hardwareStatus.append("\n\n");
```

Just use

```
hardwareStatus.setText(spannable);
```

### Old

From my understanding you are running into an infinite loop of api calls that is triggered every 5 seconds, if that is the case It's because you are calling the postDelayed function again inside the runnable, if you're looking to call the endpoint just one time then remove this line

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //do your function;
                getSystemObject();
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, apiDelayed); // Remove this
            }
        }, apiDelayed);
```

Another thing to note here is that you should be initializing the views in the

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        hardwareName = view.findViewById(R.id.hardware_name);
        hardwareStatus = view.findViewById(R.id.hardware_status);

        softwareName = view.findViewById(R.id.software_name);
        softwareStatus = view.findViewById(R.id.software_status);

        flagName = view.findViewById(R.id.flagreport_name);
    }
```

Also you're building the retrofit instance every time you call the api, it's better to create a singleton for retrofit and call the create method to initialize a global variable in your fragment or activity, then use this variable in your function like this

```
// Global variable
private WebApi api = Retrofit.getInstance().create(WebApi.class);
```

then in any function call

```
api.getNameStatus();
```

Comment: if i remove that one line then my output wont update every 5 secs. the problem is that in every auto update that the program does instead of updating the current text view that i have its adding up another set of "status".

Comment: `hardwareStatus.append("\n\n");` this line of code gives a new line for each of my status or else its going to be set horizontally with no spaces

Comment: AND `Fragment` doesn't provide the `findViewById()` method. This is provided in `Activity` or `View`. When implementing a `Fragment` you don't inflate your views in `onCreate()` (like you normally do in an Activity.) Instead, you do it in `onCreateView()` and you need to use the inflated root View to find the ID within the layout you inflated.

Comment: @YenBico what do you mean by "its adding up another set of "status" ? it'c completely normal that this is happening because you're appending new response to the old content of the textview, you need to specify more clearly what is it that you need

Comment: @YenBico AND I know that the Fragment class doesn't provide the findViewById() method, that's why I used the view param passed in the onViewCreated like this   view.findViewById

Comment: okay so basically what is happening is that in every 5 secs new content of text view is happening on my program instead of replacing my current text view from the update its adding up a new set of status so basically the auto update that the program is doing is adding a new text of status instead of just replacing the text that i currently have

Comment: @YenBico Yes but you are also appending to the old content, you need to clear the old values first and then start appending the new ones, I will update the answer top explain more

Answer (score 0):

Call `getSystemObject` from `onViewCreated` instead of from `onResume`.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    handler.postDelayed(runnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //do your function;
                    getSystemObject();
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable, apiDelayed);
                }
            }, apiDelayed);
}
```

Comment: if i remove that one line then my output wont update every 5 secs. the problem is that in every auto update that the program does instead of updating the current text view that i have its adding up another set of "status".